# Mysql Incrementing field that includes PK and Date stamp

Tags: mysql, key

I have an server side application where I need to sync down new and updated items to mobile devices. The requirement is to store one "key" that can be passed between the server and the devices to mark where we are in the syncing process. We have a millisecond timestamp field that would work for this except for the fact that when we allow customers to upload a csv file the insert process groups all those inserts together with the same timestamp, since now() sets a variable at the beginning of the transaction and uses it throughout the transaction.

The only possibilities I could come up with were doing some sort of numeric hash or CRC where I added the timestamp and pk (in this case 1045) together like CRC32(now()+1045) but that does not produce a sequential pattern over time...

The other option I was considering is modifying the batch upload process to add an incrementing millisecond value onto each item as the insert was built:

```
  insert into items (description,datemodified) VALUES 
('toaster',(now(3)+.001)),
('blender', (now(3)+.002),
('coffee maker', (now(3)+.003));
```

Then I would have a unique-enough and sequential id that I could pass back and forth to track the sync status.

Running MySQL 5.7.11, all tables are InnoDB.

Anyone solved this a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think an integer column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` might be suitable for your use case.

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
( id            BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, description   VARCHAR(80)
, datemodified  DATETIME  
, ...
, CONSTRAINT foo_UX1 UNIQUE KEY (id) 
)
;

INSERT INTO foo (id, description, datemodified)
VALUES 
(NULL,'toaster',NOW())
,(NULL,'blender',NOW())
,(NULL,'coffee maker',NOW())
;
```

Comment: It wouldn't because I need to know when/if it changes, which is where the DateModified comes in.